# How to hide accented characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, character

I have a renderPages function as shown below in which Line A prints the following output on console:

```
const renderPages = () => {
    const list = Object.keys(pagesList);
    console.log(list);  // Line A
}
```

**o/p (At console)  :**

```
0: "B"
1: "C"
2: "D"
3: "E"
4: "É"
5: "G"
6: "H"
7: "I"
8: "L"
9: "M"
10: "O"
11: "P"
12: "R"
13: "S"
14: "T"
15: "V"
16: "W"
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the function above so that it ignores `É` and accented characters from the list above.

Comment: `filter`, or a loop with an `if` statement - that's two ways you could do it

Comment: `list.filter(l => l.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)`

Comment: I think op is looking for a way to identify accented v. Non-accented char’s.

Comment: @decpk Something like this ? `const renderPages = () => {     const list.filter(l => l.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g) = Object.keys(pagesList);     console.log(list);  // Line A }`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a comparative ***array/obj*** to check for the allowed characters, then use a ***for/in*** loop to iterate over the obj and check the comparative array for a match, if so push those ***key/value*** pairs into a new object.

**NOTE:** **In the *snippits* code below, each values key is literally copied into the new OBJ, so there would be a gap in the keys where the accented key is removed...** *If you wish to create new linear indexes for the obj so there is no gap in the keys, ie: `4:"É"`, when `"É"` is removed, its key would be lost using `remove[item] = rederedPages[item]`, whereas using an iterator to place a new linear set of **indexes/keys** into the new obj would give your next value the key of `4` => `4 : "G"` and subsequently each values key following would increment by one from that spot.*

```
let i = 0;
for(item in rederedPages){ 
    // if the comparative array includes our current objs value
    if( allowed.includes(rederedPages[item])) {
      remove[i] = rederedPages[item];
      i++;
    }
  }
```

```js
const rederedPages = {..."BCDEÉGHILMOPRSTVW"} // create the obj of rendered pages with the accent

// a comparative array to compare and add allowed characters
const allowed = [..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]


// function passing an empty obj for return 
// of the accepted characters
function removeAccents(remove = {}) {
  // for in loop to iterate over obj
  for(item in rederedPages){ 
    // if the comparative array includes our current objs value
    // pass the key and value into a new obj
    allowed.includes(rederedPages[item]) ? remove[item] = rederedPages[item] : null
  }
  // return our new filtered obj which will 
  // only have accepted characters
  return remove
}

console.log(removeAccents())
```